# how can I call a stored procedure in SQL Database from Android?

Tags: java, android

Can someone please help me to have the code or a simple example how to connect to database and how to call a procedure from my Database. 
I'm a beginner :S
thanks for any help.

Comment: Which database you are using ?

Comment: this is a very old question !! here I was beginner in java and android. I will answer now what I did : I created a servlet and I used tomcat and Apache and I uploaded the servlet and i called http links witch connect to the servlet witch is calling procedures from database.. It's a very large question but I was a beginner and I didn't know that I can't call directly from my android app a stored procedure directly from the database.

Answer (score 0):

Describe what you want to do? Call stored proc on remote server or from your Android app?

If second then  read below:

Simplicity in a database engine can be either a strength or a weakness, depending on what you are trying to do. In order to achieve simplicity, SQLite has had to sacrifice other characteristics that some people find useful, such as high concurrency, fine-grained access control, a rich set of built-in functions, **stored procedures**, esoteric SQL language features, XML and/or Java extensions, tera- or peta-byte scalability, and so forth.

[Appropriate Uses For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/whentouse.html)

Comment: from my Android app. Thank you I'll check the link. I hope I can understand how to do it and I'll reply what will happen

Comment: @Chris Sim Link says there is no stored procs support in SQLite. If you want something like stored procs I recommend to use OrmLite (http://ormlite.com/sqlite_java_android_orm.shtml) library and use LINQ like queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CallableStatement](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/sql/CallableStatement.html) like ordinary JDBC calls. Be sure to include the right SQL driver jar (vendor dependent). [Example](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iadthelp/v7r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.etools.iseries.toolbox.doc/jdbccst.htm) for calling procedure using jdbc

Comment: Thank you I'll try it and i'll reply